# Asynchronous calls using postgres as an example in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

When implementing this code (example taken directly from https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres):

```
var pg = require('pg'); 

var conString = "tcp://postgres:1234@localhost/postgres";

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
  client.query("SELECT NOW() as when", function(err, result) {
      console.log("Row count: %d",result.rows.length);  // 1
      console.log("Current year: %d", result.rows[0].when.getFullYear());
      //Code halts here
  });
});
```

After the last `console.log`, node hangs. I think this is because the asynchronous nature, and I suspect at this point, one should call a callback function.

I have two questions:

1. Is my thinking correct?
2. If my thinking is correct, then how does the mechanics work. I know NodeJS is using an event loop, but what is making this event loop halt at this point?

Answer (score 6):

It appears to hang because the connection to Postgres is still open. Until it's closed, or "ended"...

```
client.end(); // Code halts here
```

Node will continue to wait in idle for another event to be added to the queue.

---

1. Not quite. This is a detail of `node-postgres` and its dependencies, not of Node or of its "*asynchronous nature*" in general.
2. The idling is due to and [documented for](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool#step-3---drain-pool-during-shutdown-optional) the [`generic-pool` module](https://npmjs.org/package/generic-pool) that `node-postgres` uses:

   > If you are shutting down a long-lived process, you may notice that node fails to exit for 30 seconds or so. This is a side effect of the idleTimeoutMillis behavior -- the pool has a setTimeout() call registered that is in the event loop queue, so node won't terminate until all resources have timed out, and the pool stops trying to manage them.

   And, as it explains under [Draining](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool#draining):

   > If you know would like to terminate all the resources in your pool before their timeouts have been reached, you can use `destroyAllNow()` in conjunction with `drain()`:
   >
   > ```
   > pool.drain(function() {
   >     pool.destroyAllNow();
   > });
   > ```
   >
   > One side-effect of calling `drain()` is that subsequent calls to `acquire()` will throw an Error.

   Which is [what `pg.end()` does](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/v0.8.7/lib/index.js#L21-L28) and [*can* certainly be done](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/214) if your intention is to exit at the end of a serial application, such as unit testing or your given snippet.

Comment: No, I don't (think) that is the answer. By calling pg.end(), you destroy all connections in a pool. In fact, the maker says that one should avoid using this. I quote: "Disconnects all clients within a pool if poolKey is provided, or disconnects all clients in all pools. Not very clean and can potentially interrupt query executions. Primarily used during testing to allow the node process to shutdown after all the tests are executed. I'm currently evaluating routes for cleaning up and shutting down client pools as gracefully as possible."

Comment: @BarrySteyn Perhaps that should be `client.end()` rather than `pg.end()`. But, as long as the connection pool is open, the Node process will continue to run. Your quote covers this: "*Primarily used during testing **to allow the node process to shutdown** after all the tests are executed.*" And, as the snippet you provided really has no reason to keep it open, being done after a single query, `pg.end()` is fine in this case.

Comment: `client.end()` does not work either (I tries it first). I understand what you are sying, but this still does not answer my two questions posed.